# the convention for persisting fake data to the database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-seeding

I want to create a bunch of fake data for my app for testing, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761888/22768246) stackoverflow answer and it seems that factories are what people use for fake data.

I read through the Laravel docs and it seems that seeders have a built in artisan command to seed the Database, while factories don't. for factories I either have to:

1. add `User::factory()->create();` somewhere in my codebase to persist fake data in the DB and later remove it
2. manually create an artisan command that runs `User::factory()->create();` under the hood

both seem to me like something the Laravel community won't settle for, so I am here asking what the solution is and if in my case I should switch to a seeder.

Comment: Common convention for testing is to start and end with an empty database, which is likely part of why Factories don't have any seeding logic. There are some cases where you need default data in your database for either your base application or for testing, in which case you'd use a Seeder to get that data in there. You can actually leverage the functionality of [FakerPHP](https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker) in your Seeder to populate your database with fake data (names, locations, etc.), and when you need specific fake instances, that's when you'd use a Factory. In my opinion anyway 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill the database with test data, [seeding](https://%20https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/seeding) is used.

```php
php artisan db:seed
OR
php artisan db:seed --class=ClassName
```

But to generate your test data you need factories that are related to your models.

To generate a new factory, use the make:factory Artisan command:

```php
php artisan make:factory UserFactory
```

This command will place the new factory class in the database/factories directory of your application and specify the path to the model

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the default state of the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

Once you have defined your factories, you can use the static factory method provided to your models by the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory` trait to create a factory instance for that model.

```
class User extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
}
```

The factory method of the `HasFactory` trait will use conventions to determine the appropriate factory for the model. Specifically, the method will look for a factory in the `Database\Factories` namespace whose class name matches the model name and has the *Factory* suffix.

**Seeder + Factory**

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

   public function run()
   {
        User::factory()->create();
        
        // Override attributes
        $user = User::factory()->create([
           'name' => 'Abigail',
        ]);
   }
}
```

Comment: so the factories runs inside the seeder, interesting..

Comment: Yes, you mostly need test data and the best place to put it is in Seeder